# Is this a new characteristic function for the primes?

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, prime-numbers, characteristic-functions

I recently found the following function, that returns $1$ if its argument is a prime number, and $0$ otherwise. Let $\chi_{\mathbb{P}}: \mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\{0,1\}$ for $n>4$ be defined as follows:
$$
\chi_{\mathbb{P}}(n)=\frac{(-1)^{\frac{2}{n}\Gamma(n)}-1}{(-1)^{-\frac{2}{n}}-1}.
$$
Then $\chi_{\mathbb{P}}$ is the characteristic function of the primes. Note that here $\Gamma$ denotes the usual gamma function.

The first few values, starting from $n=5$ are the following:

```
1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, ...
```

For convenience I include the relevant Mathematica code here:

```
 Table[((-1)^(2 Gamma[n]/n) - 1)/((-1)^(-2/n) - 1), {n, 5, 20}]
```

---

Is this already known? I have not found references to it in literature.

Comment: Characteristic function of primes is [$A010051$](https://oeis.org/A010051) in the OEIS.

There, it is given: ("`For n > 4, a(n) = (n-2)! mod n. - Thomas Ordowski, Jul 24 2016`")

$$\space n\gt 4,\space a(n) = \Gamma(n-1)\pmod n$$

Which is the closest expression to your expressions that is listed there. Both this expression and yours, are a consequence of Wilson's theorem.

Comment: As for the title, there is of course just one characteristic function of the prime numbers. You are really asking if the expression for it is new.

Comment: "Let $\chi_{\mathbb{P}}: \mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\{0,1\}$ for $n>4$ be defined" makes no sense. If you only define anything for integers exceeding $4$, then you have not defined a function with $\Bbb Z$ as domain.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Update:** This characteristic function was known since 1895. The formula$$\chi(n)=\frac{e^{2\pi i(n-1)!/n}-1}{e^{-2\pi i/n}-1}$$ appears in [Formulas for Primes](https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/Dudley30448.MM83.pdf) by Dudley (1983) which is equivalent to your formulation.

---

As $n\in\Bbb Z^+$, if $\chi_{\Bbb P}(n)=1$ then $$\chi_{\mathbb{P}}(n)=\frac{(-1)^{2\Gamma(n)/n}-1}{(-1)^{-2/n}-1}=\frac{(-1)^{2(n-1)!/n}-1}{(-1)^{-2/n}-1}=1\implies (-1)^{2(n-1)!/n}=(-1)^{-2/n}$$ which is equivalent to $$\frac{2(n-1)!}n\equiv-\frac2n\pmod2\implies2\cdot\left(\frac{(n-1)!+1}{n}\right)\equiv0\pmod2$$ which is true if the term in brackets is an integer; that is, if $n\mid (n-1)!+1$, which in turn is equivalent to [Wilson's Theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WilsonsTheorem.html).

Note that on the other hand, $$\chi_{\Bbb P}(n)=0\implies\frac{2(n-1)!}n\equiv0\pmod2\implies n\mid(n-1)!$$ so $n$ cannot be prime.

Comment: When $n=8$ what is the meaning of $(-1)^{-2/n}$? Is it $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\sqrt{-1}}}$?  Or $\frac{-1}{\sqrt{\sqrt{-1}}}$?  Is this formula supposed to give imaginary numbers?  For $n=7$ what is the meaning of $(-1)^{-2/7}$? Its value seems ambiguous.

Comment: @Michael When $n$ is even, it does not matter what value (real or complex) the (non-zero) denominator takes, as the numerator is zero from the definition of $\chi_{\Bbb P}$. When $n$ is odd, the ambiguity of the powers can be avoided as long as the $(-1)^\bullet$ terms on the numerator and on the denominator are consistently defined.

Comment: "Consistently defined" is unclear.   Perhaps it means some weird thing like $$(-1)^{2x/n} = ((-1)^2)^{x/n} = 1^{x/n} = 1 \quad \forall n \in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}$$  I don't think a formula with an unclear numerator and denominator is math.  If the formula can only be evaluated by assuming it is the same as "$(n-1)! + 1$ is divisible by $n$," then, it is better to just state this latter condition.

Comment: @Michael A choice needs to be made to evaluate each term separately. Most common would probably be $-1 = e^{i\pi}$, but every other choice yields the same end result. It is therefore unambigous and perfectly fine to write it as such.

Comment: @Klaus : Thanks.  If you write $e^{i \pi x}$ I know what you are talking about, if you write $(-1)^x$ I do not, so, I don't see much value in writing $(-1)^x$.

Comment: @Michael Yes, I agree, $e^{i\pi x}$ is better to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, this is a variant of [Wilson's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_theorem).

Comment: It's very short